# difference between foldLeft and reduceLeft in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold, higher-order-functions

I have learned the basic difference between `foldLeft` and `reduceLeft`

**foldLeft:**

- initial value has to be passed

**reduceLeft:**

- takes first element of the collection as initial value
- throws exception if collection is empty

Is there any other difference ?

Any specific reason to have two methods with similar functionality?

Comment: Recommend you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158780/difference-between-reduce-and-foldleft-in-functional-programming-particularly-s

Comment: Would be great if you edited the question to be "difference between fold and reduce in Scala".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73916338/5249621 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75724473/5249621

Answer (score 332, accepted):

Few things to mention here, before giving the actual answer:

- Your question doesn't have anything to do with `left`, it's rather about the difference between reducing and folding
- The difference is not the implementation at all, just look at the signatures.
- The question doesn't have anything to do with Scala in particular, it's rather about the two concepts of functional programming.

**Back to your question:**

Here is the signature of `foldLeft` (could also have been `foldRight` for the point I'm going to make):

```
def foldLeft [B] (z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B
```

And here is the signature of `reduceLeft` (again the direction doesn't matter here)

```
def reduceLeft [B >: A] (f: (B, A) => B): B
```

These two look very similar and thus caused the confusion. `reduceLeft` is a special case of `foldLeft` (which by the way means that you **sometimes** can express the same thing by using either of them).

When you call `reduceLeft` say on a `List[Int]` it will literally reduce the whole list of integers into a single value, which is going to be of type `Int` (or a supertype of `Int`, hence `[B >: A]`).

When you call `foldLeft` say on a `List[Int]` it will fold the whole list (imagine rolling a piece of paper) into a single value, but this value doesn't have to be even related to `Int` (hence `[B]`).

Here is an example:

```
def listWithSum(numbers: List[Int]) = numbers.foldLeft((List.empty[Int], 0)) {
   (resultingTuple, currentInteger) =>
      (currentInteger :: resultingTuple._1, currentInteger + resultingTuple._2)
}
```

This method takes a `List[Int]` and returns a `Tuple2[List[Int], Int]` or `(List[Int], Int)`. It calculates the sum and returns a tuple with a list of integers and it's sum. By the way the list is returned backwards, because we used `foldLeft` instead of `foldRight`.

Watch [One Fold to rule them all](https://youtu.be/xMhZUSEGtt0) for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: Can you explain why `B` is a supertype of `A`? It seems like `B` should actually be a subtype of `A`, not a supertype. For example, assuming `Banana <: Fruit <: Food`, if we had a list of `Fruit`s, it seems that that may contain some `Banana`s, but if it contained any `Food`s then the type would be `Food`, correct? So in this case, if `B` is a supertype of `A` and there is a list containing both `B`s and `A`s, the list should be of type `B`, not `A`. Can you explain this discrepancy?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. What my 5-year-old answer is saying about the reduce function is that a `List[Banana]` can be reduced to a single `Banana` or a single `Fruit` or a single `Food`. Because `Fruit :> Banana` and `Food :> Banana'.

Comment: Yes... that actually does make sense thank you. I was originally interpreting it as "a list of type `Banana` may contain a `Fruit`", which does not make sense. Your explanation does make sense -- the `f` function being passed to `reduce()` can result in a `Fruit` or a `Food`, which means `B` in the signature should be a superclass, not a subclass.

Answer (score 206):

`reduceLeft` is just a convenience method. It is equivalent to

```
list.tail.foldLeft(list.head)(_)
```

Comment: Good answer.  This also highlights why `fold` works on an empty list while `reduce` does not.

Answer (score 51):

`foldLeft` is more generic, you can use it to produce something completely different than what you originally put in. Whereas `reduceLeft` can only produce an end result of the same type or super type of the collection type. For example:

```
List(1,3,5).foldLeft(0) { _ + _ }
List(1,3,5).foldLeft(List[String]()) { (a, b) => b.toString :: a }
```

The `foldLeft` will apply the closure with the last folded result (first time using initial value) and the next value.

`reduceLeft` on the other hand will first combine two values from the list and apply those to the closure. Next it will combine the rest of the values with the cumulative result. See:

```
List(1,3,5).reduceLeft { (a, b) => println("a " + a + ", b " + b); a + b }
```

If the list is empty `foldLeft` can present the initial value as a legal result. `reduceLeft` on the other hand does not have a legal value if it can't find at least one value in the list.

Answer (score 6):

For reference, `reduceLeft` will error if applied to an empty container with the following error.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.reduceLeft
```

Reworking the code to use

```
myList foldLeft(List[String]()) {(a,b) => a+b}
```

is one potential option.  Another is to use the `reduceLeftOption` variant which returns an Option wrapped result.

```
myList reduceLeftOption {(a,b) => a+b} match {
  case None    => // handle no result as necessary
  case Some(v) => println(v)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The basic reason they are both in Scala standard library is probably because they are both in Haskell standard library (called `foldl` and `foldl1`). If `reduceLeft` wasn't, it would quite often be defined as a convenience method in different projects.

Answer (score 4):

From [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1) (Martin Odersky):

> The function `reduceLeft` is defined in terms of a more general function, `foldLeft`.
>
> `foldLeft` is like `reduceLeft` but takes an *accumulator* `z`, as an additional parameter, which is returned when `foldLeft` is called on an empty list:
>
> `(List (x1, ..., xn) foldLeft z)(op) =  (...(z op x1) op ...) op x`

[as opposed to `reduceLeft`, which throws an exception when called on an empty list.]

The course (see lecture 5.5) provides abstract definitions of these functions, which illustrates their differences, although they are very similar in their use of pattern matching and recursion.

```
abstract class List[T] { ...
  def reduceLeft(op: (T,T)=>T) : T = this match{
    case Nil     => throw new Error("Nil.reduceLeft")
    case x :: xs => (xs foldLeft x)(op)
  }
  def foldLeft[U](z: U)(op: (U,T)=>U): U = this match{
    case Nil     => z
    case x :: xs => (xs foldLeft op(z, x))(op)
  }
}
```

Note that `foldLeft` returns a value of type `U`, which is not necessarily the same type as `List[T]`, but reduceLeft returns a value of the same type as the list).

Answer (score 0):

To really understand what are you doing with fold/reduce,
check this: http://wiki.tcl.tk/17983
very good explanation. once you get the concept of fold,
reduce will come together with the answer above:
list.tail.foldLeft(list.head)(_)

Answer (score 0):

Scala 2.13.3, Demo:

```
val names = List("Foo", "Bar")
println("ReduceLeft: "+ names.reduceLeft(_+_))
println("ReduceRight: "+ names.reduceRight(_+_))
println("Fold: "+ names.fold("Other")(_+_))
println("FoldLeft: "+ names.foldLeft("Other")(_+_))
println("FoldRight: "+ names.foldRight("Other")(_+_))
```

outputs:

```
ReduceLeft: FooBar
ReduceRight: FooBar
Fold: OtherFooBar
FoldLeft: OtherFooBar
FoldRight: FooBarOther
```