# Reducing potentially empty RDD's

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I'm running into an issue where a filter I'm using on an RDD can potentially create an empty RDD. I feel that doing a count() in order to test for emptiness would be very expensive, and was wondering if there is a more performant way to handle this situation.

Here is an example of what this issue might look like:

```
    val b:RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(Seq("a","ab","abc"))


    println(b.filter(a => !a.contains("a")).reduce(_+_))
```

would give the result

```
empty collection
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$apply$36.apply(RDD.scala:1005)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$apply$36.apply(RDD.scala:1005)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1005)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:985)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I should go about addressing this edge case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider `.fold("")(_ + _)` instead of `.reduce(_ + _)`

Comment: Hi Dima. This is very interesting. Could you please explain? It would seem from this answer that foldleft might be a far more expensive function http://stackoverflow.com/a/25158790/2159333. Is it that the increased cost of running a foldleft would be less than the extra steps involved in an isempty or a count?

Comment: @DanielImberman The answer you referenced is about foldLeft, not fold. `fold` does not have the extra cost it is talking about, foldLeft does, although, I do think, it would indeed be significantly lower than that of counting the number of elements in the rdd.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
scala> val b = sc.parallelize(Seq("a","ab","abc"))
b: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at     parallelize at <console>:24

scala> b.isEmpty
res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: `isEmpty` does a `take(1)`, so it can also be expensive.

Comment: not nearly as expensive as a count(), filter(), reduce() or fold() would be since they all will do a full scan..

Comment: In my experience it is typical that the run time is dominated by shuffles. `take(1)` will trigger shuffles just as much as `count`. On the other hand the shuffle results will be re-used between `isEmpty` and `reduce` so maybe it's not so terrible. But `fold` is definitely the way to go!

Comment: I don't think that either count or take(1) will cause a shuffle. `fold` will still be faster than `count` (which is simply an additional wasted reduce), and approximately as fast as `isEmpty`. My preference of `fold` vs. `isEmpty` is more of aesthetic nature, as it makes the code more linear, idiomatic and readable. I don't think there is any significant difference from the performance standpoint.