# Scala Map -> Reduce vs. FoldRight

Tags: scala, dictionary, mapreduce, reduce, fold

I timed the the following two, and it appears that both of them take the same amount of time. Is there any benefit of using over the other?

```
(1 to 24).foldRight(List[Int]())((i, l) => l ::: generateList(signs, i))
```

vs.

```
(1 to 24).map(i => generateList(signs, i)).reduce(_ ::: _)
```

p.s. in my use case the order does not matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between reduce and foldLeft/fold in functional programming (particularly Scala and Scala APIs)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158780/difference-between-reduce-and-foldleft-fold-in-functional-programming-particula)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foldRight` operates in order, `map` is (theoretically) parallelizable because it's order is not defined. I do not believe that it is parallel in the current scala runtime- just that it might be in the future or on different platforms.

Comment: `someCollection.par` is parallelizable where possible (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html)