# Convert List of dataframes into single dataframe with specific columns in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to convert list of dataframes into single dataframe which given below
Where dfList is List[sql.Dataframe]

```
dfList=List([ID: bigint, A: string], [ID: bigint, B: string], [ID: bigint, C: string], [ID: bigint, D: string])

dfList = List( +--------+-------------+  +--------+-------------+ +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+
               |    ID  |     A       |   ID      |     B       | |   ID   |     C  | |   ID   |   D    |
               +--------+-------------+  +--------+-------------+ +--------+--------+ +--------+--------+
               |    9574|            F|  |    9574|       005912| |    9574| 2016022| |    9574|      VD|
               |    9576|            F|  |    9576|       005912| |    9576| 2016022| |    9576|      VD|
               |    9578|            F|  |    9578|       005912| |    9578| 2016022| |    9578|      VD|
               |    9580|            F|  |    9580|       005912| |    9580| 2016022| |    9580|      VD|
               |    9582|            F|  |    9582|       005912| |    9582| 2016022| |    9582|      VD|
               +--------+-------------+, +--------+-------------+,+--------+--------+,+--------+--------+ )
```

Excepted Output

```
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
|   ID   |     A       |      B   |  C     |  D    |
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
|    9574|            F|    005912| 2016022|     00|
|    9576|            F|    005912| 2016022|     01|
|    9578|            F|    005912| 2016022|     20|
|    9580|            F|    005912| 2016022|     19|
|    9582|            F|    005912| 2016022|     89|
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use `foldLeft` with a `join`.

#### Generating Data

```
scala> val dfList = ('a' to 'd').map(col => (1 to 5).zip(col.toInt to col.toInt + 4).toDF("ID", col.toString)).toList
dfList: List[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = List([ID: int, a: int], [ID: int, b: int], [ID: int, c: int], [ID: int, d: int])
```

Which gives me the following DataFrames:

```
+---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
| ID|  a|   | ID|  b|   | ID|  c|   | ID|  d|
+---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
|  1| 97|   |  1| 98|   |  1| 99|   |  1|100|
|  2| 98|   |  2| 99|   |  2|100|   |  2|101|
|  3| 99|   |  3|100|   |  3|101|   |  3|102|
|  4|100|   |  4|101|   |  4|102|   |  4|103|
|  5|101|   |  5|102|   |  5|103|   |  5|104|
+---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
```

#### Joining DataFrames

```
scala> val joinedDF = dfList.tail.foldLeft(dfList.head)((accDF, newDF) => accDF.join(newDF, Seq("ID")))
joinedDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, a: int ... 3 more fields]

scala> joinedDF.show
+---+---+---+---+---+
| ID|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1| 97| 98| 99|100|
|  2| 98| 99|100|101|
|  3| 99|100|101|102|
|  4|100|101|102|103|
|  5|101|102|103|104|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In Scala a `fold` is a method of reducing a collection down to a single element. In this case we are starting with the head of the list (`dfList.head`) and then joining each element in the tail of the list (`dfList.tail`) together to get one final DataFrame. `accDF` is the accumulating DataFrame (gets passed from "iteration" to "iteration") and then `newDF` is the next or new DataFrame to be added.

For more examples on how `fold` works see [here](https://coderwall.com/p/4l73-a/scala-fold-foldleft-and-foldright) or [here](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-foldleft-scala).

Answer (score 4):

@evan058 provided an effective solution, but I would like to add that `reduce` might be a better choice for [parallelized operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158780/difference-between-reduce-and-foldleft-fold-in-functional-programming-particula):

```
val joinedDF = dfList.reduce((accDF, nextDF) => accDF.join(nextDF, Seq("ID")))
```