# Difference between fold and reduce in Kotlin, When to use which?

Tags: kotlin, reduce, fold

I am pretty confused with both functions `fold()` and `reduce()` in Kotlin, can anyone give me a concrete example that distinguishes both of them?

Comment: [fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) and [reduce](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html).

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158780/difference-between-reduce-and-foldleft-fold-in-functional-programming-particula) for a deep fundamental discussion of this topic

Comment: @LunarWatcher, I saw those docs, but not getting it, that's y posted question, can u give example?

Comment: @MattKlein done

Answer (score 412, accepted):

[`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) takes an initial value, and the first invocation of the lambda you pass to it will receive that initial value and the first element of the collection as parameters.

For example, take the following code that calculates the sum of a list of integers:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).fold(0) { sum, element -> sum + element }
```

The first call to the lambda will be with parameters `0` and `1`.

Having the ability to pass in an initial value is useful if you have to provide some sort of default value or parameter for your operation. For example, if you were looking for the maximum value inside a list, but for some reason want to return at least 10, you could do the following:

```
listOf(1, 6, 4).fold(10) { max, element ->
    if (element > max) element else max
}
```

---

[`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html) doesn't take an initial value, but instead starts with the first element of the collection as the accumulator (called `sum` in the following example).

For example, let's do a sum of integers again:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).reduce { sum, element -> sum + element }
```

The first call to the lambda here will be with parameters `1` and `2`.

You can use `reduce` when your operation does not depend on any values other than those in the collection you're applying it to.

Comment: Good explanation! I'd say also, that empty collection cannot be reduced, but can be fold.

Comment: see, m at very beginner level in Kotlin, the very first example you given can you explain it more with some steps, and final answer?
would be great help

Comment: how exactly? @Miha_x64

Comment: @TapanHP `emptyList<Int>().reduce { acc, s -> acc + s }` will produce an exception, but `emptyList<Int>().fold(0) { acc, s -> acc + s }` is OK.

Comment: reduce also forces the return of the lambda to be the same type as the list members, which is not true with fold. This is an important consequence of making the first element of the list, the initial value of the accumulator.

Comment: @andresp: just as a note for completeness: it does not have to be the _same_ type. The list members can also be a subtype of the accumulator: this does work `listOf<Int>(1, 2).reduce { acc: Number, i: Int -> acc.toLong() + i }` (the list-type is Int while accumulator type is declared as Number and actually is a Long)

Comment: not sure why the kotlin docs couldn't have given a more simple example https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html

Comment: Consider that `reduce` requires at least 2 elements, else the lambda won't be executed and the first element will simply be returned without additional processing.

Comment: for those who wonder why the functions are called differently as opposed, to let's say JS. Kotlin tries to use the same names for its higher order functions as in already established FP languages such as Scala or Haskell. This makes it easier to transfer your knowledge of the concept of folding to Kotlin. See also left fold in [Hoogle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl)

Answer (score 19):

The major functional difference I would call out (which is mentioned in the comments on the other answer, but may be hard to understand) is that `reduce` **will throw an exception** if performed on an empty collection.

```
listOf<Int>().reduce { x, y -> x + y }
// java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Empty collection can't be reduced.
```

This is because `.reduce` doesn't know what value to return in the event of "no data".

Contrast this with `.fold`, which requires you to provide a "starting value", which will be the default value in the event of an empty collection:

```
val result = listOf<Int>().fold(0) { x, y -> x + y }
assertEquals(0, result)
```

So, even if you don't want to aggregate your collection down to a single element of a different (non-related) type (which only `.fold` will let you do), if your starting collection may be empty then you must either check your collection size first and then `.reduce`, or just use `.fold`

```
val collection: List<Int> = // collection of unknown size

val result1 = if (collection.isEmpty()) 0
              else collection.reduce { x, y -> x + y }

val result2 = collection.fold(0) { x, y -> x + y }

assertEquals(result1, result2)
```

Answer (score 18):

Another difference  that none of the other answers mentioned is the following:

The result of a `reduce` operation will always be of the same type (or a super type) as the data that is being reduced.
We can see that from the definition of the `reduce` method:

```
public inline fun <S, T : S> Iterable<T>.reduce(operation: (acc: S, T) -> S): S {
    val iterator = this.iterator()
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) throw UnsupportedOperationException("Empty collection can't be reduced.")
    var accumulator: S = iterator.next()
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        accumulator = operation(accumulator, iterator.next())
    }
    return accumulator
}
```

On the other hand, the result of a fold operation can be anything, because there are no restrictions when it comes to setting up the initial value.
So, for example, let us say that we have a string that contains letters and digits. We want to calculate the sum of all the digits.
We can easily do that with fold:

```
val string = "1a2b3"
val result: Int = string.fold(0, { currentSum: Int, char: Char ->
    if (char.isDigit())
        currentSum + Character.getNumericValue(char)
    else currentSum
})

//result is equal to 6
```

Comment: This is the most important. Folding is excellent for mathematical operations over a list of objects.

Answer (score 8):

**reduce** - The `reduce()` method transforms a given **collection** into a **single result**.

```
val numbers: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val sum: Int = numbers.reduce { acc, next -> acc + next }
//sum is 6 now.
```

**fold** - What would happen in the previous case of an **empty list**? Actually, there’s no right value to return, so `reduce()` throws a `RuntimeException`

In this case, `fold` is a handy tool. You can put an initial value by it -

```
val sum: Int = numbers.fold(0, { acc, next -> acc + next })
```

Here, we’ve provided initial value. In contrast, to `reduce()`, if the collection is **empty**, the initial value will be returned which will prevent you from the  `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 7):

***Simple Answer***

Result of both reduce and fold is "a ***list of items*** will be **transformed** into a ***single item***".

In case of **fold**,we provide 1 extra parameter apart from list but in case of **reduce**,only items in list will be considered.

**Fold**

```
listOf("AC","Fridge").fold("stabilizer") { freeGift, itemBought -> freeGift + itemBought }

//output: stabilizerACFridge
```

In above case,think as AC,fridge bought from store & they give stabilizer as gift(this will be the parameter passed in the fold).so,you get all 3 items together.Please note that freeGift will be available only once i.e for the first iteration.

**Reduce**

In case of reduce,we get items in list as parameters and can perform required transformations on it.

```
listOf("AC","Fridge").reduce { itemBought1, itemBought2 -> itemBought1 + itemBought2 }

//output: ACFridge
```

Comment: You should reconsider your naming for the arguments in the lambda, because freeGift will only apply to the first iteration, after that, freeGift won't have the free gift but the accumulation of the function.

Comment: @htafoya I had mentioned in example the same.Anyway Tq I had added your point so that it helps others.

Answer (score 2):

[**fold**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html):

- Takes an **initial value** (start the accumulation with this value)
- Returns the **initial value** in case the collection was empty

[**reduce**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html)

- Doesn't take an **initial value** (start the accumulation with the collection's first item)
- Throws an **UnsupportedOperationException** if the collection was empty

> **Note:** Since version 1.4 you can use [reduceOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce-or-null.html), same as **reduce** but **returns null** if the collection is empty instead of throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two functions is that fold() takes an initial value and uses it as the accumulated value on the first step, whereas the first step of reduce() uses the first and the second elements as operation arguments on the first step.