# Reverse the order of words in a String in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

I am looking for way to reverse the order of words in a string in Kotlin.

For example, the input string would be:

**What is up, Pal!**

And the output string would be:

**Pal! up, is What**

I know I need to use the reversed module, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 17):

You are correct in assuming that the **[`reversed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed.html)** module would be helpful in this task.
However to reverse the order of the words you would also need to use things like [**`split`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) and [**`joinToString`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) (or implement them yourself):

```
fun reverseOrderOfWords(s: String) = s.split(" ").reversed().joinToString(" ")

val s = "What is up, Pal!"
println(reverseOrderOfWords(s))
```

**Output:**

```
Pal! up, is What
```

Comment: Damn, that's beautifull

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
fun reverse(str:String) = str.split(" ").reduce{acc, x -> x + " " + acc}
```

Comment: fold could also work, for difference between fold and reduce, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429419/what-is-basic-difference-between-fold-and-reduce-in-kotlin-when-to-use-which