# How to reduce a string array to int value (length of the shortest element)

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin

I have a String array and I need to find what is the length of the shortest string. For example, for this string array `["abc", "ab", "a"]` I should get value `1`.

I wrote method that gets a string array and returns int value

```
val minLength = fun(strs: Array<String>): Int {
    var minLength = strs[0].length
    for (index in 1..strs.size - 1) {
        val elemLen = strs[index].length
        if (minLength > elemLen) {
            minLength = elemLen
        }
    }
    return minLength
}
```

Another approach is to use `reduce` method

```
val minLengthReduce = strs.reduce ({
    str1, str2 ->
    if (str1.length < str2.length) str1 else str2
}).length
```

Is it possible to get int value directly from `reduce()` method instead string value?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429419/what-is-basic-difference-between-fold-and-reduce-in-kotlin-when-to-use-which/44429568) about `reduce` and `fold` methods.

Should I use fold method instead reduce?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [minBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by.html)

```
val a = arrayOf("a", "abc", "b")
val s = a.minBy(String::length)?.length ?: 0
```

s will be 1.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to `map` strings to their `length` and then choose the smallest number:

```
val strs = arrayOf("abc", "ab", "ab")
val min = strs.map(String::length).min()
```