# Reduce in Kotlin: How to use properly?

Tags: kotlin, reduce

This is my code:

```
val matrix1 = arrayOf(intArrayOf(1,2))
val matrix2 = arrayOf(intArrayOf(2), intArrayOf(1))
val product = Array(matrix1.size) { row ->
    IntArray(matrix2[0].size) { col ->
        matrix1[row].indices.reduce { acc, ind -> acc + (matrix1[row][ind] * matrix2[ind][col] }
    }
}
```

The answer to this matrix multiplication is `4`. But the program returns `2`. On analyzing different input matrices, I realized the first value is not added to `acc`.

This code should work like: `1*2 + 2*1` which would equal 4. But `1*2` part is either skipped or not added to `acc`.

How do I use `reduce` properly in this situation?

Comment: The first time the lambda passed to `reduce` is executed, it will receive the first and second element of what you called it on as its parameters. You might want to use `fold` instead, which takes a separate starting value. See this answer for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429568/4465208

Comment: Thank you that solved it. I feel dumb for not realizing it!

Comment: Please give it as the answer, I will accept it