# Build error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit

Tags: kotlin, type-mismatch

I try to concatenate some barcode values:

```
barcodeScanner.process(image)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        barcodes ->
            if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                val barcode = barcodes.reduce {acc, barcode -> acc + barcode.rawValue() }
                debug ("analyze: barcodes: $barcode")
            } else {
                debug ("analyze: No barcode scanned")
            }
    }
```

The code produces the following errors:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Barcode! was expected
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public operator fun Offset.plus(offset: IntOffset): Offset defined in androidx.compose.ui.unit
public operator fun IntOffset.plus(offset: Offset): Offset defined in androidx.compose.ui.unit
Expression 'rawValue' of type 'String?' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
```

I understand none of them. Can anybody explain?

In particular the last error message sounds strange to me. Why do I try to call `rawValue` on a `String`? The variable `barcodes` should be of the type `List<Barcode>` and not `List<String>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [the function prototype of reduce](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Arrays.kt#L19236):

```
inline fun <S, T : S> Array<out T>.reduce(
    operation: (acc: S, T) -> S
): S
```

The two parameters of `operation` must have the same type, or at least there must be an implicit conversion from the second parameter (i.e. barcode) to the first (acc).

This is necessary because `reduce` uses the first element of the list as the initial value of the accumulator.

In your case, the array elements are `Barcode`, whereas the accumulator is `String`.
You may want to use `fold` instead of `reduce`.
With `fold`, you are free to choose the type of the accumulator, because you explicitly specify an initial accumulator value.
In your case that would be the empty string.

See also:
[Difference between fold and reduce in Kotlin, When to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44429419/2485966)