# Kotlin reduce function for 2d list not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to get a total size of a 2d list. This is my implementation:

```
    fun totalSize(parts: List<List<String>>): Int {
        return parts.reduce { total, next -> total + next.size }
    }
```

I get type inference fail. Required Int, Got List. But next.size should return Int.

Comment: I think the signature of reduce will force total to be the same as the inner type (e.g. List<Integer>.reduce would have an Integer total).

Comment: @CodeConfident doesn't seem that way: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html reduce operation is `operation: (acc: S, T) -> S` T being the type in the list, S the output.

Comment: There's a type constraint on the line before that: `inline fun <S, T : S>` - i.e. T (input type) must be a subtype of S (the returned type).

Comment: good point. reduce wouldn't work here. fold would.

Comment: Wow... I always thought `reduce` and `fold` were synonyms!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better: map operation during sum (from @Ruckus T-Boom comment)

```
parts.sumBy { it.size }
```

Original: map the inner lists to their sizes first (guessing Kotlin syntax):

```
parts.map { l -> l.size }.reduce { total, i -> total + i }
```

Comment: you can use `parts.map { it.size }.sum()` instead.

Comment: Or even just `parts.sumBy { it.size }`

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom - I think that's the cleanest so far; expressive & concise, and I imagine more efficient than fold since sum is presumably independent of order.

Answer (score 2):

In `reduce`, the first value for `total` is the first element of the list, which is also a list. So the inferred type for the return value of the `reduce` has to be `List`.

You can use `fold` instead:

```
return parts.fold(0, { total, next -> total + next.size })
```

Comment: @OMGPOP - I think this answer is more idiomatic for your problem! Thanks njzk2 for educating me on the difference between reduce & fold. I even continued to read more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158780/difference-between-reduce-and-foldleft-fold-in-functional-programming-particula