# Spark Fold vs Reduce in performance?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, apache-spark

In big data processing job, does function "fold" have lower computation performance compared with function "reduce" ?

For instance, I have the following two functions:

```
    array1.indices.zip(array1).map(x => x._1 * x._2).reduce(_ + _)

    array1.indices.zip(array1).map(x => x._1 * x._2).fold(0.0) {_ + _}
```

array1 is a very huge rdd array. which function has higher computation performance giving the same clustering setting.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7764875/42188) answer. There would be no difference in terms of performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between foldLeft and reduceLeft in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764197/difference-between-foldleft-and-reduceleft-in-scala)

Comment: This is not duplicate. This question is related to operations on Spark RDDs, not Scala collections.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the [same as the one pointed out by muhuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764197/difference-between-foldleft-and-reduceleft-in-scala) as the guts of the Spark implementation is merely a call to an `iterator`

`fold` from source:

```
(iter: Iterator[T]) => iter.fold(zeroValue)(cleanOp)
```

`reduce` from source:

```
iter => 
  if (iter.hasNext)Some(iter.reduceLeft(cleanF))
  else None
```

So, this is primarily just calling into the scala implementations.