# What would be a more elegant way of using case class as accumulator in foldLeft?

Tags: scala, fold

I have a case class:

```
case class Nums(num1: Int, num2: Int)
```

and a list as follows:

```
val listOfNums = List(Nums(1,1), Nums(2,2))
```

I want to return `Nums(3,3)` which is the sum of all the relevant fields with each other. The way I achieved this was:

```
listOfNums.foldLeft(Nums(0,0))((acc,nums) => {
  acc.copy(
    num1 = acc.num1 + nums.num1,
    num2 = acc.num2 + nums.num2
  )
})
```

But this feels a bit clumsy, what would be the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what you are looking for is `Reduce`, and not `fold`. You can try:

```
listOfNums.reduce((num1, num2) => Nums(num1.num1 + num2.num1, num1.num2 + num2.num2))
```

If you do want to use fold, you don't have to copy, you can just create a new `Nums`:

```
listOfNums.foldLeft(Nums(0,0))((acc,nums) => {
  Nums(
    num1 = acc.num1 + nums.num1,
    num2 = acc.num2 + nums.num2
  )
})
```

You can further read about [difference between foldLeft and reduceLeft in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7764197/2359227).

Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/hs90cT66RT2xyly7I5SY5A/5).

As @Thilo mentioned in the comment, you can add a `+` to `Nums`:

```
case class Nums(num1: Int, num2: Int) {
  def +(that: Nums): Nums = {
    Nums(num1 + that.num1, num2 + that.num2)
  }
}
```

And then the `fold` and `reduce` usage become really obviuos:

```
listOfNums.reduce(_ + _)
listOfNums.foldLeft(Nums(0,0))(_ + _)
```

Code run for that in another [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/lYoJTzH8SeqkshgNuGj3kQ/1)

Comment: Note that reduce would throw an exception on empty collections.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using [**cats**](https://typelevel.org/cats/).
Then, you can simply define a `Monoid` for `nums` so you only need to write the boilerplate once, and then reuse it in multiple parts by using auxiliary functions like `combineAll` or `foldMonoid`

```
import cats.kernel.Monoid
final case class Nums(num1: Int, num2: Int)
object Nums {
  implicit final val NumsMonoid: Monoid[Nums] =
    new Monoid[Nums] {
      override final val empty: Nums =
        Nums(num1 = 0, num2 = 0)
      
      override def combine(n1: Nums, n2: Nums): Nums =
        Nums(num1 = n1.num1 + n2.num1, num2 = n1.num2 + n2.num2)
    }
}
```

Which then can be used like:

```
import cats.syntax.all._
val listOfNums = List(Nums(1,1), Nums(2,2))
val result = listOfNums.combineAll
// result: Nums = Nums(3, 3)
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/VBXVEKSrSqCVnQl0Y874aA)*.